# In react-native, using react-native-maps, how do I end marker drag programmatically?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

My app displays a map with a polygon boundary and a marker in the middle of it.  The marker is draggable.  When the app detects that the marker has been dragged to one of the boundaries, I want to stop the drag programmatically.  It seems like this should be simple, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.  For example, I should be able to call something like onDragEnd(event)  or dragEnd(event).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I made a state variable for the marker location when it is outside the boundary:

```
  const [outside, setOutside] = useState(false);
```

Then, in the onDragStart event, I set the outside state to false.
In the onDrag event, the code is:

```
    onDrag={(event) => {
      if (outOfBounds(event) === true) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        setOutside(true);                
      }
      else {
        setOutside(false);
      }
    }}
```

This keeps the coordinates from changing as the marker is dragged outside the boundary, but it does not hide the marker.  To hide the marker, there is a conditional style on the View that defines the marker.  It is:

```
    <View style={[styles.outerMarker, {opacity: outside ? 0 : 1}]}>
```

So when the outside state is true, the opacity is 0, hiding the marker.